# am switch-user 0, not root

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, adb, stock-android

My phone is not rooted. I want to root it really bad, but it is Verizon branded, so...

I was just playing around with `am` and decided to run `am --help`.

I found `am switch-user <USER_ID>`, and ran `am switch-user 0` (I know that roots uid is 0). A brief UI popup came up saying something like: Switching to user blablabla@gmail.com. What's weird about that to me is that my phone (HTC One M7) does not SEEM to have multi user support.

Can somebody please help with this?

Also, I will be EXTREMELY happy if you can help me out with a way to root my phone. HTC One M7, Android 5.0.2, Kingroot does not work. Kingoroot does not work. Both of their pc versions do not work. Of course I can not unlock bootloader because it is Verizon. All the sketchy apps like firewater and towelroot dont work. I do have adb, and I have even set my phone up so I can use `adb connect localhost:1738` and yes I really did use that port.

I do not have the money for Sunshine, and Rumrunner results in either "Such dumb issues you have", or something like "F*** off [cant remember past this]"

Thanks in advance

Comment: That User Id 0 is of primary user in Android and does not correspond to the uid 0 of superuser.

Comment: @Firelord Ok thank you. What is the superuser User Id?

Comment: The root user that you referred to in your question is called the superuser. Its uid 0 and the User ID of the primary user (0 too) are different things.

Comment: Error: unknown command 'switch-user'